# Element is giving Error on Php page

Tags: php, html, sql

The following is my `getdata.php` script which isn't working:

```
 <?php
        $host="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="demo"; 
        $db_name="test";
        $tbl_name="test";

  mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
  mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

  $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  ?>

    <?php
        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
             <table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                <tr>
                  <td width="10%"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
                  <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
                  <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['lastname']; ?></td>
                  <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
                </tr>
             </table>
                  }
                  ?>

             <?php
                mysql_close();
             ?>
```

I’m using xampp server 1.8 with Windows XP sp2; I don't know which php version, but when I run this script it shows error `'<' unexpected ~~~~~~~`

Some error total thing is that this php is not executing tables and for per entry.  What's wrong in my script?

Comment: Yeah, so you got some error, great description. The appropiate diagnosis: Something in your code is wrong. But it is nice to know you have xampp server 1.8, because in server 1.7 you have other errors.

Comment: yes but i'm not infront of my pc i can't tell error but i can give some hints like Error unexpected ">" at line somthing line so problem is that php is not able to execute html elements

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_` database extensions, they were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and were removed in PHP 7.0.0. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions instead. And this is [why you shouldn't use `mysql_` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Sir i got this error on my script {Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/vhosts/useme.freevar.com/x.php on line 21}

Comment: `while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){` close the php tag `?>` and maybe insted of `<?` shortcode use `<?php`, than  at  `</table> }` reopen php tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error because you are trying to put HTML code directly into PHP without quoting or echoing which is what PHP is trying to tell you with 'Unexpected <'.

Your issue is here:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  <table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
      <td width="10%"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
      <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
      <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['lastname']; ?></td>
      <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
}
```

What you need to do instead is (if you wanted this on the page) add an `echo` statement and encapsulate your HTML code in quotes like this:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo "
  <table width='400' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>
    <tr>
      <td width='10%'>".$rows['id']."</td>
      <td width='30%'>".$rows['name']."</td>
      <td width='30%'>".$rows['lastname']."</td>
      <td width='30%'>".$rows['email']."</td>
    </tr>
  </table>";
}
```

All we do here is concatenate our PHP variables to the string. As far as I am aware you could also do it like this using the [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):?>
  <table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
      <td width="10%"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
      <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
      <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['lastname']; ?></td>
      <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<?php
endwhile;
```

It's also worth noting that [MYSQL_*](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) functions are now deprecated. If you can, you might want to consider using the [MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions instead.

Comment: Thank you Sir My Problem is Resolved By your Code echo "elements of html"

Comment: Sir error is  syntax error, unexpected 'hello' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/vhosts/useme.freevar.com/x.php on line 24

Comment: This is a different issue because this code doesn't contain the word 'hello'. As a guess, check your code for more situations where you have not wrapped HTML in quotes. You are more than likely doing something like `if(true){ hello }` which is not valid syntax. Instead, like this issue, you need to do `if(true){ echo 'hello'; }` instead.

Comment: No sir i put hello on <td width="10%" id="hello"> then i run php and i got this error {syntax error, unexpected 'hello' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/vhosts/useme.freevar.com/x.php on line 24 }

Comment: Watch your quotes. If you choose my first solution you'll either need to escape the quotes like this: `<td width=\"10%\" id=\"hello\">` or you'll need to use single quotes like this: `<td width='10%' id='hello'>`. The second solution may work better in this circumstance.

Comment: Thank you sir i will try this also

Answer (score 1):

PHP tags not handled properly, close it and open it appropriately.

Just add  of your code like see below -

PHP tags not handled properly, close it and open it appropriately.

Just add  of your code like see below -

```
<?php

    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="demo"; 
    $db_name="test";
    $tbl_name="test";

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
  // here is the change
  ?>
         <table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
          <tr>
              <td width="10%"><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
              <td width="30%"><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
              <td width="30%"><?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?></td>
              <td width="30%"><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
<?php      
     } // endwhile

     mysql_close();
 ?>
```

Comment: Add an explanation to your answer

Comment: under php tag you cannot write html code directly. either you have to close php tag or make echo for html code

Comment: Add explanation to your ANSWER, and something to indicate where you actually MADE A CHANGE afterall you only added 2 characters it may not be obvious to anybody else

Comment: Explain in ur answer not to me mate

Comment: please write your php start tag like <?php not <?

Comment: Sorry Blank Tables when i try my Script it show's me this error{Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/vhosts/useme.freevar.com/x.php on line 21}

Answer (score 0):

To prevent future code errors is recommended to use mysqli dbase objetct.
The code is as that:

```
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="demo"; 
$db_name="test";
$tbl_name="test";

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost",$username,$password,$db_name);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";

$res=$mysqli->query($sql);


    while($rows=$res->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
         <table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
            <tr>
              <td width="10%"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
              <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
              <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['lastname']; ?></td>
              <td width="30%"><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
   <?php }
         $res->close();
  ?>
```

PD: be carefull, you are generating one table for each register, I think you want to create one row for each register